# Installing for Ubuntu 14.04.2 stuck in a loop

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, iso

No matter what I try with ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso it keeps taking me back to the "Ubuntu installer main menu" no matter what I try.

[image]

I have validated disc media and it looks fine.

As a side note, I am connecting to this box via iDRAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by OP in Question Edit:

> Never mind, seems like an iDRAC key mapping issue. I changed iDRAC to use Java for console and it seems to work now. Not an Ubuntu problem.